# hook_cron triggered manually but not automatically

Tags: 9, cron

That hook cron below is executed when i manually trigger the cron but is not on a regular automatic base (every 3h).

How can it be ?

```
function my_module_cron() {    
  \Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice('entering hook_cron');
  //some more code
}
```

Comment: You need to schedule that yourself. Drupal has an automated cron module built in but it's a "best effort" and relies on traffic and is unreliable. People normaly use a simple crontab on their server for this, but there are any number of solutions out there

Comment: @Clive could u please list a few possible options ? are there some options not requiring server configuration? using simple_cron or ultimate cron module maybe ?

Comment: On-server is the best approach, next best is a service like pingdom. You can't schedule jobs through PHP, so you need something external to trigger it. If your task isn't critical, and can be delayed, you might be able to use the core automated cron and take the hit. Other modules won't help, they suffer from the same problem. If the task it critical/important, use an external service